# How to test SCIM service with OKTA

Tags: okta, scim

Is there any documentation on how to test SCIM service integration in OKTA developer account? I am new to using OKTA. Need to test my SCIM service with OKTA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okta's [SCIM documentation](http://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/) has a section on how to [test your SCIM server](http://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/#test-your-scim-server).